# ignoring cookies in Groovy HTTPBuilder

Tags: grails, groovy, httpbuilder

I'm getting a lot of these warning messages on a REST client call that doesn't require cookies:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-10] WARN  protocol.ResponseProcessCookies  - Cookie rejected: "[version: 1][name: mzf_in][value: 990108][domain: .xxxx.com][path: /asdf][expiry: null]". Domain attribute ".xxxx.com" violates RFC 2109: host minus domain may not contain any dots
[http-bio-8080-exec-10] WARN  protocol.ResponseProcessCookies  - Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: mzf_dr][value: 0][domain: .xxxx.com][path: /asdf][expiry: Wed Dec 31 21:00:00 ART 1969]". Illegal path attribute "/asdf". Path of origin: "/xyz"
```

I want to disable the cookie processing in the Groovy HTTPBuilder calls I'm using. Googling I found that there is supposed to be a way to "set the policy to ignore cookies" (http://lists.canoo.com/pipermail/webtest/2006q2/005902.html) in the "httpclient params". Tried adding that to my Groovy/Grails code but couldn't make it work. Didnt find any information related to this in the official HTTPBuilder site. 
Anybody has configured the IGNORE_COOKIES option in Groovy/Grails HTTPBuilder? Can somebody provide a more specific example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago I did with the following piece of code:

```
import static org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY
import static org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES

def http = new AsyncHTTPBuilder(
   poolSize: conf.getInt('client.poolSize'),
   uri: conf.getString('client.url'),
   contentType: JSON
)
http.client.params.setParameter(COOKIE_POLICY, IGNORE_COOKIES)
http.client.params.setParameter('http.connection-manager.max-total', 50)
http.client.params.setParameter('http.connection-manager.max-per-host', 50);
http
```